# css из браузера в VS Code

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

как в vs code можно реализовать функционал - правишь стили в devtools chrome и все записывается в файл стилей? в sublime можно такое делать.

Comment: Я имел ввиду что-то подобное http://livestyle.io/

Answer (score 1):

насколько я помню делается так, переходишь во вкладку sources потом в overrides добавляешь папку https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSpvp.png подтверждаешь доступ, потом выбираешь в папке нужный файл для правок - правишь код нажимаешь ctl+ S все.